# On hover focused blue background color

Tags: css, hover, focus, java-8

I am having one strange problem, though I have good knowdedge about css and all. But in javafx I am facing strange situation. When I take cursor away from the MenuItem, the background color goes blue.

Here is my code

```
                            <MenuButton id="scMenuButton" fx:id="searchCriteriaMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" text="Search Template" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true">
                                <items>
                                    <!-- <MenuItem id="scMenuItem" fx:id="scMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-margin: 0;">
                                        <graphic> -->
                                        <CustomMenuItem id="#searchCustomMenuItem" fx:id="scMenuItem" hideOnClick="false" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-margin: 0;" styleClass="redBorder">
        <content>
                            <VBox id="searchMbox" fx:id="advancedSearchVbox" prefHeight="406.0" prefWidth="359.0" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" visible="false">
                                <children>
                                    <AnchorPane id="searchAnchorPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="615.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="noborder">
                                        <children>

                                            <HBox layoutY="76.0" minHeight="168.0" minWidth="345.0" prefHeight="168.0" prefWidth="357.0">
                                                <children>
                                                    <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" maxHeight="230.0" minWidth="355.0" prefHeight="216.0" prefWidth="355.0" vbarPolicy="AS_NEEDED">
                                                        <content>
                                                            <VBox fx:id="userSelectedValues" fillWidth="true" layoutY="5.0" maxWidth="355.0">
                                                            </VBox>
                                                        </content>
                                                    </ScrollPane>
                                                </children>
                                            </HBox>
                                            <Group layoutY="-100.0">
                                                <children>

                                                    <HBox layoutX="7.0" layoutY="350.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="348.0">
                                                        <children>
                                                            <Text layoutX="7.0" layoutY="335.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Template Name">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets right="5.0" top="9.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                            </Text>
                                                            <ComboBox fx:id="templateNameComboBox" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="330.0" prefWidth="248.0" promptText="Select Template Name">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="7.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                            </ComboBox>
                                                        </children>
                                                    </HBox>

                                                    <HBox layoutX="7.0" layoutY="385.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="348.0">
                                                        <children>
                                                            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Type of template">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets top="9.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                            </Text>
                                                            <ComboBox fx:id="templateTypeComboBox" prefWidth="248.0" promptText="Select Template Type">
                                                                <items>
                                                                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                                        <String fx:value="Private" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="Public" />
                                                                    </FXCollections>
                                                                </items>
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="5.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                            </ComboBox>
                                                        </children>
                                                    </HBox>
                                                    <HBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="-8.0" layoutY="422.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="360.0">
                                                        <children>
                                                            <CheckBox fx:id="defaultTemplate" mnemonicParsing="false" />
                                                            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Set as a default template">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets top="3.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                            </Text>
                                                        </children>
                                                    </HBox>
                                                    <HBox layoutX="5.0" layoutY="450.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="352.0">
                                                        <children>
                                                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSaveTemplate" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton" text="Save Template" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                           <cursor>
                                                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                           </cursor></Button>
                                                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onEditTemplate" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton" text="Edit Template" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                           <cursor>
                                                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                           </cursor>
                                                            </Button>
                                                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDeleteTemplate" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton" text="Delete Template" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                           <cursor>
                                                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                           </cursor>
                                                            </Button>
                                                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClearTemplate" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="55.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton" text="Clear" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                           <cursor>
                                                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                           </cursor>
                                                            </Button>
                                                            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#advancedSearch" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="55.0" styleClass="advancedRedButton" text="Search">
                                                                <HBox.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="8.0" />
                                                                </HBox.margin>
                                                           <cursor>
                                                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                           </cursor>
                                                            </Button>
                                                        </children>
                                                    </HBox>
                                                </children>
                                            </Group>
                                            <HBox layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="348.0">
                                                <children>

                                                    <GridPane fx:id="gridPane" hgap="3.0" layoutX="6.6" layoutY="60.6" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="348.0" vgap="1.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="-3.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="51.0">
                                                        <columnConstraints>
                                                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="132.99999237060547" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
                                                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="102.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="102.0" />
                                                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="115.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="86.0" />
                                                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="76.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="28.0" />
                                                            <ColumnConstraints />
                                                        </columnConstraints>
                                                        <rowConstraints>
                                                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="140.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="24.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="275.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="48.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                        </rowConstraints>
                                                        <children>
                                                            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Field" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="35.9765625" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="CENTER">

                                                                <styleClass>
                                                                    <String fx:value="boldFont" />
                                                                    <String fx:value="px16Font" />
                                                                </styleClass>
                                                            </Text>
                                                            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Operator" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">

                                                                <styleClass>
                                                                    <String fx:value="boldFont" />
                                                                    <String fx:value="px16Font" />
                                                                </styleClass>
                                                            </Text>
                                                            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Value" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER">

                                                                <styleClass>
                                                                    <String fx:value="boldFont" />
                                                                    <String fx:value="px16Font" />
                                                                </styleClass>
                                                            </Text>
                                                            <ComboBox fx:id="fieldName" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select Field" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                                                <items>
                                                                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                                        <String fx:value="CLSMESSAGEID" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="PAYMENTTYPE" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="REQUESTTYPE" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="VALUEDATE" />
                                                                    </FXCollections>
                                                                </items>
                                                            </ComboBox>
                                                            <ComboBox fx:id="operator" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select Operator" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                                                <items>
                                                                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                                                        <String fx:value="IN" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="NOT IN" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="EQUALS" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="NOT EQUALS" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="LESS THAN" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="LESS THAN EQUALS" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="GREATER THAN" />
                                                                        <String fx:value="GREATER THAN EQUALS" />
                                                                    </FXCollections>
                                                                </items>
                                                            </ComboBox>
                                                            <TextField fx:id="fieldValue" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                            <Button fx:id="addImage" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addOptions" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="20.0" styleClass="addImg" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                                                <GridPane.margin>
                                                                    <Insets left="5.0" />
                                                                </GridPane.margin>
                                                           <cursor>
                                                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                                                           </cursor>
                                                            </Button>
                                                        </children>
                                                    </GridPane>

                                                </children>
                                            </HBox>
                                        </children>
                                    </AnchorPane>
                                </children>
                            </VBox>

                                        </content>
    </CustomMenuItem>
                                        <!-- </graphic>
                                    </MenuItem> -->
                                </items>
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets left="6.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                       <styleClass>
                          <String fx:value="redButton" />
                          <String fx:value="whiteText" />
                       </styleClass>
                            </MenuButton>
```

Comment: Can you please add you code in fiddle.

Comment: I just tried to recreate the malfunction via jsfiddle. As far as i understand your problem, it appears the moment you comment out or remove the <cursor></cursor> items in your <MenuItem></MenuItem> element (Please correct me if i'm wrong, since your question isn't that clearly described to me). Therefore i just commented out the <cursor> elements but couldn't trigger the error. Did you tried to comment out the, regarding the error, irrelevant elements? If you did so, please use the simplified version of your code and paste it via http://jsfiddle.net/ on your question

Comment: I got the fault in my .css file. Thank you for your time sir.